# Yii project on a subfolder using htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, yii

I have a Yii application on cpanel that is located on /home/domain_folder/public_html/portal/yii_application and I put a .htaccess inside yii_application folder
with the following code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php
```

now I need to rewrite the url using a .htaccess on root folder /home/domain_folder/public_html
and remove /portal/yii_application on the url. I tried this one

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/portal/yii_application
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ portal/yii_application/$1 [L]
```

but it's not working it still append portal/yii_application on my url
even if I typed on domain.com/admin/site/login,
here is my config.php url rule

```
'urlManager' => array(
            'urlFormat' => 'path',
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'rules' => array(
                '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>'
            ),
        ),
```

I'm not good on .htaccess, I've been trying to solve this for 6 hours now.
Is there anyone here who can help me with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Condition and rule seem ok. Maybe the **AllowOverride** directive for the public_html directory is set to **None** and it just **ignores .htaccess** file.

You should set it to

```
AllowOverride FileInfo
```

I don't know how this works with cpanel, but usually you can find this in apache config files under /etc/apache2/ or /etc/httpd

Comment: thanks for your reply, it seems that cpanel doesn't have httpd or apache2 on etc folder

Comment: Try this cpanel [documentation](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/EA/Advanced+Apache+Configuration)